# Apache Avro generated POJO

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, avro

I am using Apache avro with kafka to serialize/deserialize the messages,
I would like to know if there is a way to use avro without using the generated POJO (not very readable) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you're talking about Avro's [`GenericRecord`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericRecord.html):

```java
final KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));

while (true) {
  final ConsumerRecords<String, GenericRecord> records = consumer.poll(100);
  for (final ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record : records) {
    final GenericRecord value = record.value();
    System.out.printf("the value of userId: %s%n", record.get("userId");
  }
}
```

The down side of this is that you'll have to know and check for the existence of the field's key you're using `GenericRecord#get()` on.